# Cobra CMD does not executes completly

Tags: go, go-gin, go-cobra

I have the following code, is really simple. The point is that the code after the first fmt.Println is never executed. Any idea why?

The code creates a random string, and then creates a Gin Router. The code that executes the router is never being runned.

```golang
func send(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {

    randomString = createRandomString()
    fmt.Println("Code for share: " + randomString)
    var files filesToSend = args

    //Create http to listen to port
    g := gin.Default()
    g.GET("/", files.sendHttpHandler)
    g.Run()
}
```

Comment: How do you know it's never executed? How are you invoking `send`? Where's `main`?

Comment: The whole code is [here](https://github.com/mariogmarq/GoShare). The server is not being created(or at least it doesn't report that is running, which should be doing since is not in production mode). Also putting any other Println command after that one won't work. Anything runs after that println

Comment: Try adding `panic("exit")` before `g.Run()` instead of a plain `fmt.Println`, does the code reach it or does it not?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't panic. Should I create an issue in github?

Comment: Your module path and import paths do not match, every invocation of the command is using probably a cached "dependency" that is not the actual "live" source.

Comment: i.e. `GoShare` is not `goshare`.

Comment: remove this: https://github.com/mariogmarq/GoShare/blob/master/go.mod#L7 and fix case in this: https://github.com/mariogmarq/GoShare/blob/master/main.go#L18

Comment: it worked!! Thank you!! Didn't know that Golang cached dependencies

Comment: I believe only those dependencies that are remote to the project, and because the import in your main did not match up with the module's path, go went ahead and downloaded the source for `...goshare/cmd` from github and cached it. When the paths match, then the dependency is local and is not cached but instead used "directly".

Comment: Go itself caches dependencies in the [modcache](https://golang.org/ref/mod#module-cache).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is the `import path` in `main.go` vs the module name in `go.mod`. The capitalization is different:

```golang
package main

import "github.com/mariogmarq/goshare/cmd"
```

go.mod:

```golang
module github.com/mariogmarq/GoShare
```

It is best practice to use all lowercase for package (and module) names. From the [Go Blog](https://blog.golang.org/package-names):

> Good package names are short and clear. They are lower case, with no under_scores or mixedCaps.

Comment: Didn't see you meanwhile figured it out in the comments as well...